# Modificar el porcentaje de un filtro con jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, filtro

tengo un problema que me trae de cabeza.
Tengo en el html unos inputs para seleccionar el filtro css que quiero aplicar y el porcentaje.
Recojo todos los datos en variables, pero no se cómo modificar el estilo. Normalmente con ().css(propiedad,valor) se podría modificar, pero el filtro sería (filter: propiedad(valor%) :(

En el html tendría:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" id="porcentajeEfecto" >% 
<input type="button" value="Aplica Efecto" id="btnAplicaEfecto">
<img id="fotoCoche1" class="fotoColage" src="./IMG/01.jpg" alt="Imagen coche 1">
```

En el css:

```
.fotoColage{
    border: 2px solid black;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: sepia(0%);
    filter: invert(0%);
}
```

Lo normal en JQery sería:

```
$('.fotoColage').css('border-radius', '8px')
```

Con esto puedo modificar el border_radius, pero no se hacerlo con el filter: grayscale(porcentajeEfecto %)

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mismo sugieres, usa `.css("filter", "sepia(32%)")`, solo que para insertar los valores de manera dinámica, usa las plantillas literales de javascript. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
$( "#btnAplicaEfecto" ).click(function() {
   var porcentaje = $("#porcentaje").val()
   $("#foto")
     .css("filter", `grayscale(${porcentaje}%) sepia(${porcentaje}%) invert(${porcentaje}%)`)     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" id="porcentaje" >
<input type="button" value="Aplica Efecto" id="btnAplicaEfecto">
<br>
<img id="foto" class="fotoColage" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200" alt="Imagen">
```

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!! He dejado el código así, ya que el tipo de efecto también lo había recogido en una variable:
'''''
$('.fotoColageRojo').css('filter',`${efecto}(${porcentaje})`)
'''''